# preg_replace, string and numeric replacement

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

So this is a preg_replace associated question i guess,

I have a string with multiple repeating patterns

they all formated as:

```
some string :22: more text :12: etc
```

how do i replace the ":" around them with some different char?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$string = 'some string :22: more text :12: etc';
$regex = '/:(\d+):/';
$newString = preg_replace($regex, "@$1@", $string);
```

**Note**: You have to replace the '@' in the second parameter with the char you want (also different chars before and after the numbers).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Misunderstood original question. However, is still a flexible option:

```
$result = str_replace(":22:", "tag", "some string :22: more text :12: etc");
$result = str_replace(":12:", "other_tag", $result);
```

Replace the ? character with your replacement character.

Comment: i'd like to replace like: "text 22 moretext" diffrent values on both sides

Comment: Ah. That is more clear than your original question. Then @Aurelio is more correct.

Answer (score 0):

Sbustitudes `_` for `:` around numbers:

```
preg_replace('/:(\d+):/', '_$1_', 'some string :22: more text :12: etc');
```